# Como usar o v-for com componentes, usando array?

Tags: array, vue.js, for, component

Estou utilizando a pergunta abaixo pra ilustrar melhor minha dúvida.

[Vue não está renderizando tabela com v-for, como resolver?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/390976/vue-n%c3%a3o-est%c3%a1-renderizando-tabela-com-v-for-como-resolver)

Como eu faço pra fazer a mesma coisa? Só que exibindo uma listagem, usando componente, mas ao invés de um usar um `array` de objetos, quero usar um `array` simples, como:

```
produtos = ['tv','computador','celular']
```

***Observação:*** ainda estou aprendendo a usar o **StackOverflow**, não sei se estou fazendo da melhor forma, usando a referência desse modo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para imprimir uma lista de um `array` com uma dimensão é da mesma forma que imprimir um `array` de ***objetos***, exemplo:

Exemplo simples:

### ```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#editor',
  data: {    
    produtos: ['tv','computador','celular']
  },
  methods: {
      addUser: function() {
        console.log('clicado');
      }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="editor">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="produto in produtos">{{produto}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Exemplo com componente:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component('list-product', {
  props: ['produto'],
  template: '<li>{{ produto }}</li>'
})


new Vue({
  el: '#editor',
  data: {    
    produtos: ['tv','computador','celular']
  },
  methods: {
      addUser: function() {
        console.log('clicado');
      }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="editor">
  <ul>
    <list-product
     v-bind:key="produto"
     v-for="produto in produtos" 
     v-bind:produto="produto"></list-product>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Leitura:

- [Renderização de Listas - Array em Elementos com v-for](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)
- [Array em Elementos com v-for](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-em-Elementos-com-v-for)

Outros exemplos de código:

- [Inserir valor de Input como uma Option de um Select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/437430/inserir-valor-de-input-como-uma-option-de-um-select/437435#437435)
- [Renderizar Valores Input Dinâmico - VueJS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/454290/renderizar-valores-input-din%c3%a2mico-vuejs/454303#454303)
- [Converter imagem para base64 usando VueJS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242834/converter-imagem-para-base64-usando-vuejs/242878#242878)
- [Como filtrar uma lista em vue com resposta ignorando acentos e maiúsculo/minúsculo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/325007/como-filtrar-uma-lista-em-vue-com-resposta-ignorando-acentos-e-mai%c3%basculo-min%c3%bascu/325040#325040)

Comment: Dessa forma eu entendo, mas queria saber como faço pra exibir usando um componente.

Comment: da mesma forma não tem diferença quando tem um componente porque se vai passar via `props` vou colocar outro exemplo

Comment: Fiz o exemplo com componente simples @GustavoRodrigues, como você não tem um foco especifico é criado um exemplo minimo